# OpenLayers 3: logo position and style

Tags: css, openlayers, openlayers-3

If I add logo to the map

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  logo: true
});
```

How can I change the position of the logo to be on top left corner and change  it's size?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this but [according to the documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html) you can pass [logo options](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/olx.html#LogoOptions) instead of a boolean.

In the logo options there are properties like offset, style, position... which should help achieve what you are asking for.

Options are made using a JavaScript object, so comma separated key/value pairs `{ style : ..., offset: ...}`.